# Python Scraping empty tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have a problem with scraping some element from a page:
https://tuning-tec.com/mercedes_w164_ml_mklasa_0507_black_led_seq_lpmed0-5789i

code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL="https://tuning-tec.com/mercedes_w164_ml_mklasa_0507_black_led_seq_lpmed0-5789i"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title=soup.find(class_="product_cart_title").text
price=soup.find(class_="icon_main_block_price_a")
number=soup.find(class_="product_cart_info").findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')[1]
description=soup.find(id="tab_a")


print(description)
```

Problem is when I want to get to: `tab_a`

And its a problem cause inside

```
<div align="left" class="product_cart_info" id="charlong_id">
</div>
```

is empty. How I can get it? 
I see its about js i think. Maybe there is some delay when the page loads?

Comment: this page use JavaScript to add element to page so requests/Beautifusoup is uselees because they can't run JavaScript - you may need Selenium to control web browser which runs JavaScript. OR you can try to use `DevTools` in Firefox/Crhome to find url used by JavaScript to get these elements from server - and then you can use this url with requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the info is loaded via JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. But you if you look to Chrome/Firefox network tab, you can see where the page is making requests:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tuning-tec.com/mercedes_w164_ml_mklasa_0507_black_led_seq_lpmed0-5789i'
ajax_url = 'https://tuning-tec.com/_template/_show_normal/_show_charlong.php?itemId={}'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('.product_cart_title').get_text(strip=True))
print(soup.select_one('.icon_main_block_price_a').get_text(strip=True))
print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Symbol") ~ td').get_text(strip=True))

item_id = re.findall(r"ajax_update_stat\('(\d+)'\)", soup.text)[0]
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(ajax_url.format(item_id)).content, 'html.parser')

print()

# just print some info:
for tr in soup2.select('tr'):
    print(re.sub(r' {2,}', ' ', tr.select_one('td').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')))
```

Prints:

```
MERCEDES W164 ML M-KLASA 05-07 BLACK LED SEQ
1788.62 PLN
LPMED0

PL
Opis
Lampy 
 soczewkowe ze światłem 
 pozycyjnym LED. Z dynamicznym 
 kierunkowskazem. 100% nowe, w komplecie 
 (lewa i prawa). Homologacja: norma E13 - 
 dopuszczone do ruchu.
Szczegóły
Światła pozycyjne: DIODY Kierunkowskaz: DIODY Światła 
 mijania: H9 w 
 zestawie Światła 
 drogowe: H1 w 
 zestawie Regulacja: elektryczna (silniczek znajduje się w 
 komplecie).
LED TUBE LIGHT Dynamic Turn Signal >>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little change in the description, I don't know if it's working, have a look on the following code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://tuning-tec.com/mercedes_w164_ml_mklasa_0507_black_led_seq_lpmed0-5789i'
ajax_url = 'https://tuning-tec.com/_template/_show_normal/_show_charlong.php?itemId={}'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')


def unwrapElements(soup, elementsToFind):
    elements = soup.find_all(elementsToFind)
    for element in elements:
        element.unwrap()

print(soup.select_one('.product_cart_title').get_text(strip=True))
print(soup.select_one('.icon_main_block_price_a').get_text(strip=True))
print(soup.select_one('td:contains("Symbol") ~ td').get_text(strip=True))

item_id = re.findall(r"ajax_update_stat\('(\d+)'\)", soup.text)[0]
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(ajax_url.format(item_id)).content, 'html.parser')
description=soup2.findAll('tr')[2].findAll('td')[1]
description.append(soup2.findAll('tr')[4].findAll('td')[1])

unwrapElements(description, "td")
unwrapElements(description, "font")
unwrapElements(description, "span")


print(description)
```

I need just these elements of description in English language. It will be OK?

And anyway thanks for help !!

Only one thing i don't know why he didn't remove all